# Make a custom iso of current Ubuntu set up

Tags: 12.04, installation, custom-distributions, remastersys

I have been running on a dual boot of Windows and 12.04 for quite some time now. Primarily because of space constraints and the fact that I might not have booted into Windows in the last 6 months, I would like to format the entire machine with Ubuntu.

While, I am aware of the method followed to remaster the original iso and make a custom one, I do not know how an iso of my current setup can be created. It is of utmost importance that I use my current setup because I've configured my build according to the projects I work on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a non-uefi system then you can use remastersys to do so. It should be noted that remastersys is a dead project.

Install Remastersys 3.0.4-2 On Ubuntu 13.04 - Desktop X86-64:

http://postbin.djun.net/pages/article5.php