# OS to iso installed all apps

Tags: server, 16.10

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 server and installed all applications I need.

Now my question is how to convert that all into iso?

Comment: It is difficult. Is it really necessary? Maybe what you want is a backup or a cloned image, so that you can restore your server, if something happens to your current system?

Comment: Hi @Mohit Balumi, Just to clarify, you want to save the current state of your Ubuntu OS (with all the installed applications and settings) into an iso so that you can install/use that later on a different computer?

Comment: I think his is talking about cloning his system IMO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a disk image and restore from it later?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later) and possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make an EXACT ISO of my system to put on other computers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/320826/is-it-possible-to-make-an-exact-iso-of-my-system-to-put-on-other-computers) or [How to make an iso of my installed system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730985/how-to-make-an-iso-of-my-installed-system)

Comment: As my requirement is
I need ubuntu server with custom logo and our applications installed 
and kickstart installation

Answer (score 1):

Pinguybuilder is exactly what you need. It's a fantastic software, built by Pinguy OS developers, forked from the great original Remastersys.

The script can create a livecd of the installed system and works with *buntu systems.

You can either make a distributable livecd or a backup of your system.

Notable Changes:

Single package for Script and GUI.
Full EFI support including EFI partition on ISO.
Populate pool folder with grub-efi for offline installing.
Update grub entry with the named used for the CD label.
Uses XZ to compress the filesystem.squashfs for smaller ISO size.

Version 3.* works with *buntu systems 14.04 (should also work with 14.10, if not try 4.*)

Version 4.* works with *buntu systems 15.04+

For download, please visit [here](http://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/).

The Pinguy Builder will create a installable ISO of your current system. You can then burn that ISO to a USB using something like Unetbootin or just burn the ISO directly to a DVD. The DVD/USB can then be booted from a PC.

Depending on what option you choose determines what type of ISO gets created.
If you pick “Dist”, this will backup the whole system but exclude your home folder and any personal info.

If you pick “Backup”, this will backup the system and will include you home folder (so make sure it isn’t to big).

Both options can run as a live session. “Dist” mode has no password to login. “Backup” mode uses the user name and password used to create the ISO.

**Lastly, don't forget to make the installer executable before the fresh installation, else, it won't run.**

Comment: please add the steps here for how to actually achieve what OP wants

Comment: There is no special step really, the website link I provided has everything. It's a download and run software scenario.  And, since, he needs to backup his server as iso, I believe, that is possible without using a GUI, although, I always used with GUI.

Comment: This answer is in the Low Quality Posts review queue - someone has flagged it. You have gained a significant amount of reputation here, so you know how the site works and that "link-only-answers" are considered not an answer, since the post would be useless if the link dies. In the case where the link is to a piece of software that does everything for you, I agree that the post could be useful, and that there is no way to salvage it if the link dies anyway, so it's a tricky case, but you can still improve your answer by adding details of how to install and run the software.

Comment: This link is actually the Pinguy OS website. However, sourceforge has https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/ this too. As far as description goes, I really don't have any screenshot handy. I personally used it to backup my old Xubuntu 16.04 installtion as iso. It works like a charm. Hope it helps.

Comment: I know it is the official website and that however much detail you add to your answer it will still only be useful if the project remains available. I wasn't suggesting adding more links, but more instructions :( Please [edit] your answer with additional information, rather than leaving it in the comments

Comment: Edited as much as possible by me. Thanks @Zanna.

Comment: That's great, thanks very much! I have upvoted your answer, but someone has already downvoted it, unfortuantely :(

Comment: I appreciate @Zanna